# Can't access JSON object information React/Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

Feels like I'm missing something obvious here - but I can't figure out how to access my JSON data. I have a Container component:

```
class About extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    const APP_URL = 'http://localhost/wordpress/'
    const PAGES_URL = `${APP_URL}/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`

    this.props.fetchAllPages(PAGES_URL, 'about')
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <div className="bg">
          <div className="home-wrapper">
            <h1>AAAAABBBBBOOOOUUUUUT</h1>
            <Counter/>
            <AboutInfo />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchAllPages }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(About);
```

And a Smart component:

```
class AboutInfo extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.page);
    console.log(this.props.page.id);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is ID: {this.props.page.id}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ page }) => {
  return { page }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AboutInfo);
```

My action:

```
export const fetchAllPages = (URL, SLUG) => {
  var URLEN;

  if(!SLUG){
    URLEN = URL
  } else {
    URLEN = URL + "?slug=" + SLUG
  }

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchRequest());
    return fetchPosts(URLEN).then(([response, json]) => {
      if(response.status === 200){
        if(!SLUG) {
          dispatch(fetchPagesSuccess(json))
        } else {
          dispatch(fetchPageBySlugSuccess(json))
        }
      } else {
        dispatch(fetchError())
      }
    })
  }
}

const fetchPageBySlugSuccess = (payload) => {
  return {
    type: types.FETCH_PAGE_BY_SLUG,
    payload
  }
}
```

My reducer:

```
const page = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PAGE_BY_SLUG:
      console.log(action.paylod)
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This gives me:

[image]

When I console.log(this.props.page) in my AboutInfo component, it prints the object, but when I print console.log(this.props.page.id) it gives me **undefined**. Why can't I print the JSON content? Thanks!

Comment: page seems to be an array. How about this.props.page[0].id?

Comment: @HenrikStåhlberg Then I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" :(

Comment: The screenshot of the object does not show the whole object. If you extend it at "AboutInfo.js:6" it would be easier to track down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**page is an array** and hence `this.props.page.id` is `undefined`. You might want to access the first element in array in which case you would do

```
this.props.page[0].id
```

but you might also need to add a test, since before the response is available you will be trying to access `page[0].id` and it might break.

You could instead write

```
this.props.page && this.props.page[0] && this.props.page[0].id
```

Comment: @ShubhamKatri when I try to console.log(this.props.page[0]) or console.log(this.props.page[0].id) I only get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" :(

Comment: That is the reason I mentioned to add a conditional check

Comment: But will I always need to write "<h1>This is ID: {this.props.page && this.props.page[0] && this.props.page[0].id}</h1>" when I want to access a value? @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: @fransBernhard, you need to write the conditional check when the data is not initially available. Flow types are really useful in such cases

Comment: I've been trying some things, read https://hackernoon.com/redux-flow-type-getting-the-maximum-benefit-from-the-fewest-key-strokes-5c006c54ec87 , but I cant really see how to work it - could you perhaps write an example? Or where I would use Flow types? @ShubhamKhatri

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from the store is async So you must adding loading varibale on your reducer

```
class AboutInfo extends Component {
 render(){
  if(this.props.loading) return (<div>loading</div>);
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>This is ID: {this.props.page.id}</h1>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ page, loading }) => {
 return { page, loading }
}
```

on your action try returing

```
json.page[0]
```

Comment: When I try it I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" :(

Comment: not this.props.page[0].id do this.props.page.page[0].id

Comment: Thank you for answer! When I try dispatch(fetchPageBySlugSuccess(json.page[0]) action I similairly get "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: use one of this solutions

Comment: Still the same issue with this.props.page.page[0].id

Comment: console.log(this.props.page.page) ?

Comment: Tried changing my action - and console.log(this.props.page.id) which gave me "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". And tried haveing action as it were and console.log(this.props.page.page[0].id) which gave me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". So darn frustrating ..

Comment: console.log(this.props.page.page) gives me undefined @Dkhillamine

Comment: do console.log(json) in your action and show us your reducer your must passing the correct object from action

Comment: @Dkhillamine I added my reducer above, and your right, when I console.log(action.payload) it says "undefined". But I'm confused - it adds it to state in the logger :'(

Comment: when i console.log(json) in my action - the object is printed

Comment: i untrestand the problem , you must add loding variable on your reducer , and not return your component until loading finish, and data on your reducer must be initialised empty

Comment: the answer you choose is correct because loading data is async but not like that we do to fetch data on react redux

Comment: Thank you so much, do you by any chance have an example of how I would do this?

Comment: this is a complete example react and redux action and reducer https://github.com/dkamine/react-responsive

Answer (score 0):

That is because `page` is an array and the `id` is a property of its 1st element.

So use `this.props.page[0].id`

If the logged object in your screenshot is the `this.props.page` then you will need and additional `.page` as that is also a part of the object `this.props.page.page[0].id`

Comment: Thank you for response @Gaby , console.log(this.props.page[0].id)  and console.log(this.props.page.page[0].id) just gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" :(